# Hide class when another class is loaded via  Ajax in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, show-hide

I have two classes. I want to hide `frontpage_message` class when `content_message` class appears. Problem is that I load stuff with Ajax where `content_message` class is located.

Below is my code. Works fine without Ajax.

```
// This is in Frontpage
<div class="frontpage_message">Frontpage Message</div>

// This is loaded with Ajax
<div class="content_message">Content Message</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".content_message").text().length > 0) {
    $('.frontpage_message').hide();
   }                                           
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume you have a ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
   if($(data).find('.content_message').length){
          $('.frontpage_message').hide();
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me more info how to implement this? In head of index.html I have included jquery.js and script.js where this code is located. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

in your success call back try this....

```
 function(responseValue) {
       if($(responseValue).find('div').hasClass('content_message')){
          $('.frontpage_message').hide();

      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it working. Can you give me more detailed info where to put this code? Without Ajax my original code works fine. In head of index.html I have included jquery.js and script.js where this code is located. Is that right?